# Multiple pdf creation using vsmoraes/laravel-pdf

Tags: php, pdf, laravel-5, dompdf

I am using vsmoraes/laravel-pdf for pdf creation. For single pdf creation it works fine. But when I am trying to create multiple pdf it shows the error 
**No block-level parent found. Not good.**
This is what i am doing in my controller code to generate pdf. Need help, thanks.

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Vsmoraes\Pdf\Pdf;

class HomeController extends BaseControler
{
    private $pdf;

    public function __construct(Pdf $pdf)
    {
        $this->pdf = $pdf;
    }

public function helloWorld()
{
    $html = view('pdfs.example1')->render();
    for ($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) {
        $this->pdf->load($html, 'A3')->filename(public_path() . $i)->output();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I can't answer wrt using this library. However, current versions of dompdf can load only a single document at a time. It looks like this library instantiates dompdf once, so you would need to find a way to instantiate this library on each loop.

Answer (score -1):

```
public function helloWorld()
{
    $html = view('pdfs.example1')->render();
    for ($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) {
        return $this->pdf->load($html)->show();
    }
}
```

The `for` always exits from `helloWorld()` at the first loop. Are you sure you want this to behave this way?

Comment: I have edited my question. I just want to create multiple pdf using for loop and save in a file. Hope u will understand now.

Comment: you can't ask a question by writing an answer? what's the point?